# How to automatically map JSON to Java Class in Spring Controller

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, http-status-code-415

I have got the following code:

```
public class MyClass {

    String xxx;
    String yyy;

    public String getXxx() {
        return xxx;
    }
    public void setXxx(String xxx) {
        this.xxx = xxx;
    }
    public String getYyy() {
        return yyy;
    }
    public void setYyy(String yyy) {
        this.yyy = yyy;
    }
    public MyClass(String xxx, String yyy) {
        super();
        this.xxx = xxx;
        this.yyy = yyy;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass [xxx=" + xxx + ", yyy=" + yyy + "]";
    }
}
```

I also implemented the service:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
class MyService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")

    public @ResponseBody
    String add(@RequestBody String myClass, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

        return "Test";
    }

}
```

When I do an HTTP call with DEV HTTP CLIENT with JSON:

> {"xxx":"abc", "yyy":"abc"}

[image]

I see an error:

> Error 406 NOT_ACCEPTABLE

Is it possible to do it in this way or I have to encode JSON and create a Java Object?

Comment: Do you have the Jackson libraries (http://jackson.codehaus.org/) available on your classpath?  This should be seamless when they are present (with a relatively vanilla configuration).

Comment: No, it isn't but I am not sure if it is a solution

Comment: You keep using strings instead of your class. `@ResponseBody` should generally return the POJO representing the JSON response. Also, explicitly setting the `produces` value is redundant (and prevents Spring from returning XML, in case that matters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add *produces="application/json"* in *@RequestMapping*

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
class MyService {

@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = "application/json" )
    public @ResponseBody String myMethod( @RequestBody String _json,HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
        return _json;
    }   
}
```

[image: this the result with postman extension for chrome]

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe there is a problem with data which I send from DEV HTTP CLIENT...

Comment: add to myMethod constructor request and response and change the type of myClass in String. Then parse the string in myClass.

Comment: myMethod( @RequestBody String myClass,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response )

Comment: I did it, now I got the: **Error 406 NOT_ACCEPTABLE**

Comment: in my test web application works, try without request and respons, then return the myClass String.

Comment: Could you show me the request you sent? Which tool you use?

Comment: i use postman extension for chrome, i edited my post with screenshot

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with google GSON in your controller.

here is example:

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonElement s = gson.toJsonTree(device, Devices.class);
            return s.toString();
```

and do not forget for @ResponseBody

Hope it will be helpfull